# How to make listbox display search results based on input in form?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I got a table called "dbInventory" with "ID, InvName, InvQuantity, InvType" and a entry form matching these columns.

What I'm trying to achieve is to have the listbox start displaying search results based on the input.

(My ID column contains barcodes, not autonumbers)

So for instance, if I scan a barcode for an item I already put in the table some other time, I would like it to appear on the listbox right away.

How would one go about that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are wanting to deal with two different methods of entry - either by scanning a barcode (which would give you the entire barcode) or by the user typing the barcode in.

I would suggest using two controls in tandem - a text box, where the user can either scan a bar code or else type in the start of the barcode (and delete typed in data), and then a list box where matches are displayed.

You can use the text box's Change event to get the .Text property and use that as the basis of the list box's RowSource:

```
Private Sub txtSearch_Change()
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    If Not (IsNull(Me!txtSearch.Text)) Then
        Me!lstInventory.RowSource = "SELECT ID, InvName, InvQuantity, InvType FROM dbInventory WHERE ID LIKE '" & Me!txtSearch.Text & "*' ORDER BY ID ASC;"
    Else
        Me!lstInventory.RowSource = "SELECT ID, InvName, InvQuantity, InvType FROM dbInventory ORDER BY ID ASC;"
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "frmInventory!txtSearch_Change", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

I'm not sure whether scanning a barcode into the text box will trigger the OnChange event - it should do!!

If you are now using 2 different controls to search (part matching on ID and Name) then you should use a small procedure that creates the RowSource of the ListBox as needed, and then call it from the OnChange event of either text box. Something like the code below should get you started:

```
Private Sub txtSearchID_Change()
    Call sSearchForInventory(Nz(Me!txtSearchID.Text, ""), Nz(Me!txtSearchName.Value, ""))
End Sub
Private Sub txtSearchName_Change()
    Call sSearchForInventory(Nz(Me!txtSearchID.Value, ""), Nz(Me!txtSearchName.Text, ""))
End Sub
Sub sSearchForInventory(strID As String, strName As String)
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim strSQL As String
    If Len(strID) > 0 Then
        strSQL = " AND ID LIKE '" & strID & "*' "
    End If
    If Len(strName) > 0 Then
        strSQL = strSQL & " AND InvName LIKE '" & strName & "*' "
    End If
    If Left(strSQL, 4) = " AND" Then
        strSQL = "WHERE " & Mid(strSQL, 6)
    End If
    Me!lstInventory.RowSource = "SELECT ID, InvName, InvQuantity, InvType FROM dbInventory " & strSQL & " ORDER BY ID ASC;"
    Me!lstInventory.Requery
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sSearchForInventory", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

Notice that you need to use the .Text property of the control that is being changed, but the .Value property of the other control.

Regards,

Comment: However, how would i make this pull data based on multiple values?
I would like the Name field be another criteria once i edit the txtName i created under txtSearch which name i changed to txtID.
I have copied this code into the _change event of said txtName, but i was not successful with the sql syntax taking both values.
Here is what i have tried: SELECT ID, InvName, InvQuantity, InvType FROM dbInventory WHERE ID LIKE '" & Me!txtID.Text & "*' AND InvName LIKE '" & Me!txtName.Text & "*' ORDER BY InvName ASC;

Comment: instead of AND i have also tried "+" and "OR" but all of them give me an error 2185:You can't reference a property or method for a control unless the control has focus.

Comment: The .Text property of a control is only used when the control has the focus (it is basically data that hasn't been committed to the database). If the control does not have the focus, you would use the .Value property. If you are doing a search based on 2 different controls, you may want to move the RowSource creation to a private sub within the form, and then you can call it from either control.

Comment: would you perhaps have some study material where i might find clues on how to do that? I'm quite new to access and vba and i don't know how yet how to ask the questions properly to get  the information i need. I don't know how to make the RowSource into a new Private Sub and then call for it too.

Comment: You are AMAZING @Applecore , thank you so very much!

Comment: I'm trying to edit this code you provided me to work for a single field now but with no success, would you mind giving me some clarification on the code so that i would be able to do that? I especially don't understand   
 If Left(strSQL, 4) = " AND" Then
        strSQL = "WHERE " & Mid(strSQL, 6)

Comment: This part of the code basically takes the SQL string that has been built up, removes the "AND" at the start of it, and then adds "WHERE" so that it can be properly joined into the rest of the SQL statement that is used as the RowSource. You can put some `Debug.Print strSQL` into the code at various points to see how it is being built, or else you can just step through the code line by line looking at the Locals Window to see the variables change.

Comment: oh thank you, but just tell me please what do the numbers represent? (4 and 6)

Comment: `Left(strSQL,4)` means take the left 4 characters of the string `strSQL`, and `Mid(strSQL,6)` means take everything to the right of the 5th character of `strSQL`, so if `strSQL` were equal to "123456789", `Mid(strSQL,6)` would return "6789".

Comment: Private Sub txtSearchID_Change()
    Call sSearchForInventory(Nz(Me!txtSearchID.Text, ""), Nz(Me!txtSearchName.Value, ""))
End Sub
this will not work with combo boxes, or will it? Im getting no results

Comment: A combo box works slightly differently, as it starts to automatically filter down based on what text the user has entered. I think that if you have any further queries, you should start a new question as this is moving away from the original question.

Comment: Ok i got it to work with a combo box, however only when i select the option within the drop down, not when i write it in, is there a way to do that?