# LIKE statement taking multiple parameters

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to pull data from two columns `ID` and `InvName` from a table `dbInventory`, at the same time using two text boxes `txtID` and `txtName` with no success.

Here is my code:

```
SELECT ID, InvName, InvQuantity, InvType
FROM dbInventory
WHERE ID LIKE '" & Me!txtID.Text & "*' AND
      InvName LIKE '" & Me!txtName.Text & "*'
ORDER BY InvName ASC;
```

How would I properly write this code?

Comment: Also see this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61227416/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Property *Text* is not accessible when the control hasn't focus. So try using *Value*:

```sql
SELECT 
    ID, 
    InvName, 
    InvQuantity, 
    InvType 
FROM 
    dbInventory 
WHERE 
    ID LIKE '" & Me!txtID.Value & "*' AND 
    InvName LIKE '" & Me!txtName.Value & "*' 
ORDER BY 
    InvName ASC;
```